# Always getting last value from array while in loop

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have array which contains 1 sub array. From that array I have to make format like:

```
    '2012-05-08': {
        dots: [{
            key: 'vacation',
            color: 'blue',
            selectedDotColor: 'white'
        }, {
            key: 'massage',
            color: 'red',
            selectedDotColor: 'white'
        }],
        selected: true
    },
```

So I used reduce method and get all dates as a key. Now the object which I am getting is for some particular date like:
[{…}, {…}]

And final result I am getting is this:
2019-05-08: {dots: Array(1)} which is just taking the last object in an array.

Actual format I want is:
2019-05-08: {dots: Array(2)} . // length of sub array

I have tried using reduce, map , forEach, but all of them return last value of the array

```
let temp = responseJson.data.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
          console.log('current val.... ', currentValue);
          let key = moment(currentValue.event_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD');

            previousValue[key] = currentValue.events;


          return previousValue;
        }, {});
```

Output of temp:
2019-04-16: (2) [{…}, {…}]
...

```
eventDates = responseJson.data.map(({ event_date} ) => moment(event_date).format('YYYY-MM-DD'));
// array of date string
```

```
if(eventDates.length) {
          let eventRecord;

          eventDates.map((date) => {
            eventRecord = temp[date];
            this.setState({ eventData1 : eventRecord.reduce((previousValue, currentValue) => {
              previousValue[date] = {
                dots: [{
                    key:currentValue._id,
                    color: 'black'
                }]
              }

              return previousValue
            }, {}) }, () => console.log('states... ', this.state.eventData1))

            })
        }
```

This is the response json:

```
carerId: "5cad711296b53f1d16b137d0"
event_date: "2019-04-17T12:32:36.131Z"
events: (2) [{…}, {…}]
grandpaId: "5cad8a5cb5b125269edd816b"
```

Comment: Please format your arrays.

Comment: I formatted the array.

Comment: and your Json format?

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning 1 element for dots in reduce handler. Need to assign current value of dots as well as new value. Using spread array ES6.

```
dots: [
  ...((previousValue[date] && previousValue[date].dots) || []),
  {
    key:currentValue._id,
    color: 'black'
  }
]
```

Btw please do not call setState in the map function

Comment: Its throwing an error of:
'dots is undefined'

dots is not predefined in array. I want it in output.

Comment: Yes. We need to check if dots is exist for a particular date before access it. Updated the answer